# Compare an array to mutiple rows and delete them in the listbox

Tags: excel, vba

So the problem is that I want to compare an array to a mutiple rows that have two values. A value of an array is linked to a line in the listbox. If an value of the array is between these two values then the linked line in the listbox has to be deleted.

So a value of a cell in the red box cant be between the two values in the green box, orange box, blue box etc. [schematic despcription](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygXZY.png)

These values are linked with values you fill in the userbox. So when the tile berekenen (calculate) is pressed, the awnsers wil be shown in the listbox. 
[Userbox with listbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIT9d.png)

So my first thought was to color the values that are between the two values and  based on that to delete them out of the listbox. But with no succes, I cant figure it out on my own anymore. This is my whole code:

```
Private Sub Bereken_Click()
'Invullen van de cellen na het indrukken van de bereken knop'
If boogbreedte.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("cannot Empty!")
Else
    Range("Blad1!C2").Value = boogbreedte.Text
End If
 If koppelstriplengte.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("cannot Empty!")
Else
    Range("Blad1!C4").Value = koppelstriplengte.Text
End If
 If gatafstand.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("cannot Empty!")
Else
    Range("Blad1!C5").Value = gatafstand.Text
End If
 If stramienenafstand.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("cannot Empty!")
Else
    Range("Blad1!C6").Value = stramienenafstand.Text
End If
 If aantalstramienen.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox ("cannot Empty!")
Else
    Range("Blad1!C7").Value = aantalstramienen.Text
End If  'Uitlezen waarden'
With Blad3
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Range("A1:Z10").Value
Dim ii As Long, jj As Long
For ii = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
    For jj = LBound(arr, 2) To UBound(arr, 2)
        If arr(ii, jj) >= Range("AA11").Value And arr(ii, jj) <= Range("AB12").Value Then
        Cells("A1:Z10").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
        End If
        Next jj
        Next ii

End With



'Na het drukken op de berekenknop naar volgende tab'
    Pons.MultiPage1.Value = 1



'Uitlezen ponsafstand'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long, rw As Long
Dim Myarray() As String


Set ws = Sheets("Blad1")

    'welke cellen uitlezen'
Set rng = ws.Range("F2:L11")

With Me.ListBox1
    .Clear
    .ColumnHeads = False
    .ColumnCount = rng.Columns.Count

    ReDim Myarray(rng.Rows.Count, rng.Columns.Count)

    rw = 0

    For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
        For j = 0 To rng.Columns.Count
            Myarray(rw, j) = rng.Cells(i, j + 1)
        Next
        rw = rw + 1
    Next

    .List = Myarray

        'kolom breedte en aantal'
    .ColumnWidths = "20;10;20;15;25;10;20"
    .TopIndex = 0
End With
```

Thanks for your time already

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can use a range as an array, so `Myarray=rng.value`    Have you tried this yourself in the code?

Comment: No i have not, but I should give it a try. Thanks for the tip